# Is there any way to assign text field value to a variable through the App class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to assign a kivy text field value to a variable through the App class

This is a bit different case as the text field is placed inside a box layout which is registered as a Factory widget

This is the code

```
from kivymd.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

# this is object 1 which will be added to main grid

<object_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 
    id:obj_1

    TextInput:
        size_hint:None,None 
        id:txt



#main grid

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    size_hint_y:None
    adaptive_height: True
    height:self.minimum_height 

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size_hint_y:None 
        adaptive_height:True
        height:self.minimum_height 
        id:sc_grid          
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text: 'Add 1'
            on_press:
                app.add_1()          
                    
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text: 'Assign value'
            on_press:
                app.Assign()                
                
'''

class MyApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    
    def add_1(self):
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(Factory.object_1())

    # this crashes

    def Assign(self):
        txt_1=self.root.ids.txt.text
        
MyApp().run()
```

I've asked a similar question before but i didn't got any appropriate answers, so i decided to upload one with more clarification

In the above code

●on pressing the button Add1 ,
Factory widget(BoxLayout) which contains the text field is added to the main Layout

●I've also created another button 'Assign value' to assign the value to a variable

I want it to be assigned though the app class itself

You have the complete freedom to do any modifications as i only need the logic behind it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ids` defined in the `kv` are only added to the `ids` dictionary of the widget that is the root of the rule where the `id` is defined. So the `txt` `id` will not appear in the `BoxLayout` that is the root widget of the `App`. That `id` will only appear in the `ids` of an instance of `object_1`. So you may need to save a reference to the added `object_1`, like this:

```
def add_1(self):
    self.obj_1 = Factory.object_1()
    self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(self.obj_1)
```

Then you can access the `txt` `id` like this:

```
def Assign(self):
    txt_1=self.obj_1.ids.txt.text
```

Of course, if the `add_1()` method gets called more than once, you will only be able to reference the last added `object_1`.

On another note, any class names used in `kv` should be capitalized. Doing otherwise may cause syntax errors. So, you should rename `object_1` to `Object_1`.